# Apache Cloudstack Console Proxy access via API

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I make use of the cloudstack API, to integrate into a 3de party portal. I would like to access the console proxy via the API, cant find the API methods to do so.

Ie get the session token for the specific virtual machine and open up the ajax window from our 3de party portal.

The management server should expose the Console Proxy to use via the API, then I assume you should acquire a token based on login credentials, or via the API for the specific Virtual Machine you have access to.

If someone done this before, would be appreciated to share some detail related to this request.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for Console Proxy I solved this problem per below :

Use the same authentication procedure the normal cloudstack api use defined her - http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/developersguide/dev.html

Use the same API Key and sign the request with API Secret provided from Cloudstack:

The Console proxy endpoint are as follow - /console?cmd=access&vm=xxx, on success a Url will be returned with a token to access the virtual machine.

Test Results -

Request:
CloudstackRequestClientFilter -> cmd=access&vm=29603248-6d8a-4582-aa9a-4d1bfb4d7714&apikey=3NRrdrhDTwggQ_oQny11dD39-XRWJxCd0dh2xqtMNShrz_jb4ZdhHtmRh7NYiOfRzLNwPcBVAfT9FHh9v96vzg&response=json&signature=u4c7QZNQNcN+2s3fhRNSHTyl7+Q=

Response :
frame src="http://172.16.90.99/ajax?token=TCbfnguNvsHEkga3jPJEfZctqiPHTEynM6sAG2K8iIuioKHU8UU1QAWuQLHATd0dznP9vXPggHJp9km_1bmmStiD1PPKr6nZeid0NVI7kUt8_vOGkOK4vdM2d388KFj8oA280mQ-ZjPHWPgU4gCn47nLVb-2cVxNgOijOjdgDEDj5vlqFkzz2YhcqkLt6CIVdFcAJ1g1gqvhrO530ubjLZsiQvxs_kn9X8eXMafhRm_qugu3k6lLuG38zXsK9jKNWkmqoAV2EBBZh-r6agm4dQ">

Hope this helps, took met sometime to figure this out, source for the console proxy can be found here :
https://github.com/apache/cloudstack/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/cloud/servlet/ConsoleProxyServlet.java